# Two CLOB values need to append in DB2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

```
Set ls_total=ls_concat1 || ls_cocat2;
```

Getting "is too long" error came

Note:ls_concat1,ls_cocat2,ls_total are CLOB datatypes

Comment: what is the definition of `ls_total` ?

Comment: its a final output, two clob values need to concat and store in ls_total

Answer (score 0):

The `CLOB` data type has length in Db2.
It's obvious, that a variable must have an appropriate length to hold the result value.
There is no error in the example below, but you get it, if you define `ls_total` as `CLOB (9)` - with insufficient length.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE ls_total CLOB (10);
    --DECLARE ls_total CLOB (9);

    DECLARE ls_concat1, ls_concat2 CLOB (5);
    
    SET ls_concat1 = 'ABCDE', ls_concat2 = 'ABCDE';
    SET ls_total = ls_concat1 || ls_concat2;
END@
```

If it doesn't answer your question, then post some reproducible example which returns the error you mentioned.